# Transfer data with UDP protocol in PHP - Can't assign requested address

Tags: php, macos, sockets, udp

**I ddevelop in mac.**

stream_socket_server(): unable to connect to udp://192.168.50.191:1234 (Can't assign requested address)

What's the matter? Thanks for your help.

```
$socket = stream_socket_server("udp://192.168.50.191:1234", $errno, $errstr, ST$
if (!$socket) {
    die("$errstr ($errno)");
}

do {
    $pkt = stream_socket_recvfrom($socket, 1, 0, $peer);
    echo "$peer\n";
    stream_socket_sendto($socket, date("D M j H:i:s Y\r\n"), 0, $peer);
} while ($pkt !== false);
```

Comment: Can you please display your all code here ?

Comment: ok. I just add up my code. Do the ip(192.168.50.191:1234) machine must to  install a udp server.

Comment: I fix this problem. Because I monitor other machine's ip.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need run as root user.
On Windows working without admin privileges.

Comment: I have use sudo to run this.